# get reverse_iterator from device_ptr in CUDA

Tags: cuda, thrust

For a device_vector, I can use its `rbegin()` method to get its reverse iterator. But how to construct a reverse iterator directly from device_ptr?

May be this can be achieved by constructing a device_vector with the device_ptr, the code is as follows:

```
thrust::device_ptr<int> ptr = get_ptr();
thrust::device_vector<int> tmpVector(ptr , ptr + N)
thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key(tmpVector.rbegin(), tmpVector.rend(), ......);
```

But I don't know if `thrust::device_vector<int> tmpVector(ptr , ptr + N)` will construct a new vector and copy the data from ptr or it just reserve a reference from ptr? The documentation of Thrust doesn't mension this.

Any ideas?

Comment: `thrust::device_vector<int> tmpVector(ptr , ptr + N)` will construct a new vector and copy the data from `ptr`.  You could use a permutation iterator to iterate in reverse over a `device_ptr` sequence using the method I demonstrated in my answer to [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666621/thrust-fill-isolate-space).

Comment: @RobertCrovella, yes, I noticed the way you do that, I modified the code you provide and replaced the line 89 to `thrust::inclusive_scan_by_key(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), az.rbegin(), asr.rbegin(), head_flag_predicate<int>());` so that I don't need to use `ra`, which saved me both time and memory. But in my own program, my array of `a` is provided by others as `device_ptr`, so I'm thinking about if I can transfer `device_ptr` to `device_vector` so that I can still use `rbegin()`

Comment: You can copy the `device_ptr` array to a device vector.  I don't believe you can wrap a device vector in-place around a device_ptr array.

Comment: To make a reverse iterator from any kind of iterator, including `device_ptr`, use the `thrust::make_reverse_iterator` function.

Comment: @JaredHoberock, thanks, it works. And does `thrust::make_reverse_iterator` create extra array to achieve reversed read of `device_ptr` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing an answer based on the comment by Jared, to get this off the unanswered list, and to preserve the question for future readers.

To make a [reverse iterator](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1reverse__iterator.html) from any kind of iterator, including `thrust::device_ptr`, use the `thrust::make_reverse_iterator` [function](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__fancyiterator.html#ga948fb9912096b65f973aa779ae4de31f).

Here is a simple example:

```
$ cat t615.cu
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/reverse_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>
#define DSIZE 4
int main(){

  int *data;
  cudaMalloc(&data, DSIZE*sizeof(int));
  thrust::device_ptr<int> my_data = thrust::device_pointer_cast<int>(data);
  thrust::sequence(my_data, my_data+DSIZE);
  thrust::copy_n(my_data, DSIZE, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator Iterator;     
  thrust::reverse_iterator<Iterator> r_iter = make_reverse_iterator(my_data+DSIZE); // note that we point the iterator to the "end" of the device pointer area
  thrust::copy_n(r_iter, DSIZE, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","));
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t615 t615.cu
$ ./t615
0,1,2,3,
3,2,1,0,
$
```

The creation of a reverse iterator does not create any "extra array".