# find nearest non-zero element in another vector in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

There is a M x N matrix **A** and **B**.(Actual size of matrix is 512 x 4096)
In each row of A, the points to be processed are set to 1.
And each row of B contains values obtained through a specific operation.
Based on each row, I am going to do an operation to get the value of B that is closest to the point of 1 in A.
The example is shown in the figure below, and the code I wrote in MATLAB was also written down.
Here's how I thought of it:

Pick the non-zero element index of A with thrust. And for each element, the closest value is fetched from the corresponding row of B by for-loop.
(If there are several non-zero elements in A, it is expected to be slow.)

I want to make good use of the power of the GPU for this operation, do you have any more efficient ideas?

[image]

```
[idxY,idxX] = find(A == 1);
for Point = 1:length(idxY)
    pointBuf = find(B(:,idxY(Point)) == 1); // find non-zero elements in Row of B
    if ~isempty(pointBuf)                   // there are non-zero elements in Row of B
        [MinValue, MinIndex] = min(abs(pointBuf - idxY(Point)));
        C(idxY(Point),idxX(Point)) = B(pointBuf(MinIndex(1)),RangeInd(Point)); // Get closest point in B
    else
        C(DopInd(Point),RangeInd(Point)) = 0; // if there is no non-zero elements in Row of B, just set to 0
    end
end
```

Comment: The example matrices look as if you might want to use a sparse matrix format for this. How many nonzero elements do you expect (as a percentage)?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666621/thrust-fill-isolate-space) may be of interest.

Comment: @powermew What is the range of possible values of the elements of `B`?

Comment: @paleonix The number of nonzero elements are under 4096.

Comment: @njuffa It should be double value elements of B.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you! After I study it, can I ask question about it with my case?

Comment: See Robert's link. First fill out B, then element-wise select=multiply with A. I would fill out B in a normal Cuda kernel (without Thrust) by shifting all elements first left by one, taking the new value only, if the previous value was zero, then shifting right, then left, and so on. The intermediate result would be kept in registers and shared memory instead of the global memory to speed things up. You can do some operations per row within a thread, some within a warp with shuffle instructions and some within a block with shared memory. One row has 4096 elements.

Comment: Process one row with one warp. As you have double elements with 8 bytes, better store indices into the original rows with 2 bytes (or use native 4 byte ints). Each thread of the warp for this row is responsible for 4096/32=128 elements. Shift 4095 to the left and shift 4095 to the right in an interleaved way. The 512 rows are processed by the SMs and by the number of warps per SM. The actual computation including shuffle between threads without global load / store of this simple approach should run in about 250 microseconds (depending on GPU model of course).

Comment: You basically do a morphological image operation in 1D to fill out the zeros by letting the non-zero elements creep one by one. That is well parallelizable. And the sizes make it okay to design for the worst-case.

Comment: @Sebastian Is it possible to process 512 rows simultaneously with your kernel idea?  
 It seems little bit hard to me, but I will research about using register and shared memory for your suggestions.

Comment: If one warp processes one row, then you would need 512 active warps (you would not even need to process the rows at once, but we assume you want). A RTX 2060 for example has 30 to 34 SMs (depending on variant), which support up to 32 active warps each. The greater difficulty with the shown approach is that 512 is small than that it is large. Let us run 16 warps per SM.

Comment: A RTX 2060 supports 65536 4-byte-registers per SM. As a warp has 32 threads, one thread would have 128 4-byte registers. This would be a bit too few to store 128 values (<-4096/32) (as there would be no registers left). So either shared memory would be needed or probably better, the number of warps per SM reduced to 12, so 168 registers would be available per thread. And the 512 rows would be done in two iterations.

Comment: As registers cannot be indexed on Nvidia, the for loops in the program would need #pragma unpack to automatically unroll the loops instead of spilling to local memory. The algorithm is simple enough to keep the program small (so it still fits into the instruction cache).

Comment: @Sebastian What keywords should I search for in order to study such knowledge?
 I wrote the code that works at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73862737/how-to-improve-finding-nearest-non-zero-element-in-another-vector-in-cuda).

Comment: Use Compute Nsight for profiling. You learn a lot about Cuda by understanding what it shows. And you get to know, what the current bottleneck is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as reference a solution, which shifts left and right by 4095. It has similarities with bubble sort variants, which bubble up and down at the same time.

Advantage is that it does not depend on the position of the non-null elements in `B` and can be easily parallelized between threads.

But the inner loop, which translates to 2 SASS instructions is still just too slow (too often called): The program takes 26ms on my notebook.

It would do so in the best and the absolute worst case of the input matrices.

Parts and methods of it probably can be reused, as it shows some CUDA programming methods.
So more or less for reference, in the end not a final (fast enough) solution:

```
__global__ void calcmatrix(bool* A, double* B, double* C)
{
// calculate row number
    int row = blockDim.x * gridDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (row >= 512)
        return;

// store index of valid double from B, this is moved up and down
// those indices are for the current thread. Each thread is responsible for 128 consecutive columns.
    int indices[128];

// prefill the indices with their own number (as if every double from B is valid)
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
        indices[i] = threadIdx.x * 128 + i;

// Store zero flags (4 * 32 bits) for our 128 elements
    unsigned int myzeroflags[4];

// For efficiently loading data from memory, we distribute the data in another way: thread 0 gets columns 0, 32, 64, 96, ...; thread 1 gets columns 1, 33, 65, 97, ...; thread 2 gets columns 2, 34, 66, 98, ...; and so on

#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
// load value from B
        double in = B[row * 4096 + i * 32 + threadIdx.x];
// compare to zero (!in) and combine all bool results from the 32 threads (__ballot_sync))
        unsigned int zeroflag = __ballot_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, !in);
// store the ones, which belong to us
        if (threadIdx.x == i / 4)
            myzeroflags[i & 3] = zeroflag;
    }

// go through our zero flags and set those indices to -1 (there is already a valid index "0", so we use a negative number to signify invalid)
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
#pragma unroll
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++)
            if (myzeroflags[i] & (1 << j))
                indices[i * 32 + j] = -1;

// main loop, do 4095 times
#pragma unroll 1
    for (int i = 0; i < 4095; i++) {
// move all elements to the left (if the index there is invalid)
// send index over thread boundaries
        int fromright = __shfl_down_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, indices[0], 1, 32);
#pragma unroll
// if left index is -1, set it to one index to the right
        for (int j = 0; j < 127; j++)
            if (indices[j] == -1)
                indices[j] = indices[j + 1];
// move over thread boundaries (except for the rightmost thread)
        if (threadIdx.x != 31 && indices[127] == -1)
            indices[127] = fromright;

// move to the right in the same way as to the left
        int fromleft = __shfl_up_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, indices[127], 1, 32);
#pragma unroll
        for (int j = 127; j > 0; j--)
            if (indices[j] == -1)
                indices[j] = indices[j - 1];
        if (threadIdx.x != 0 && indices[0] == -1)
            indices[0] = fromleft;
    }

// for the other distribution of elements for memory accesses, we have to redistribute the indices to the correct threads
// To not have bank conflicts, we define the shared memory array with 33 instead of 32 elements in the last dimension, but use only 32. With this method we can put threadIdx.x into the last and previous to last dimension without bank conflicts
    __shared__ short2 distribidx[8][32][33];

    int indices2[128];

// Redistribute first half; the index can go from 0..4095 (and also theoreticially -1, if there was no non-null element in this row). This fits into a short, convert for faster transfer
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        distribidx[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x][i] = { static_cast<short>(indices[i]), static_cast<short>(indices[i + 32]) };
    __syncwarp();
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        short2 idxback = distribidx[threadIdx.y][i][threadIdx.x];
        indices2[4 * i + 0] = idxback.x;
        indices2[4 * i + 1] = idxback.y;
    }

    __syncwarp();
// Redistribute second half

#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        distribidx[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x][i] = { static_cast<short>(indices[i + 64]), static_cast<short>(indices[i + 96]) };
    __syncwarp();
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        short2 idxback = distribidx[threadIdx.y][i][threadIdx.x];
        indices2[4 * i + 2] = idxback.x;
        indices2[4 * i + 3] = idxback.y;
    }

// Do final calculation
#pragma unroll
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
// Default value is zero
        double result = 0;
// Read only, if A is true and indices2 is valid
        if (A[row * 4096 + i * 32 + threadIdx.x] && indices2[i] != -1)
// Read B with calculated index (this read is not optimized/coalesced, because the indices can be wild, but hopefully was or can be cached)
            result = B[row * 4096 + indices2[i]];
// Store result in C
        C[row * 4096 + i * 32 + threadIdx.x] = result;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool* A;
    double* B;
    double* C;
    cudaMalloc(&A, 2 * 512 * 4096);
    cudaMalloc(&B, 8 * 512 * 4096);
    cudaMalloc(&C, 8 * 512 * 4096);
// called in this fashion
    calcmatrix<<<(512 + 7) / 8, dim3(32, 8)>>>(A, B, C);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed comments. I am studying it in details.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is really far from being simple to implement efficiently on a GPU. The main reason is that GPUs are designed to efficiently execute **SIMD-friendly algorithm** while this problem can hardly be solve in a SIMD friendly way.

The naive solution you propose will be very inefficient due to the many small kernels to execute (starting a kernel is expensive and Thrust tends to run them synchronously by default AFAIK), not to mention the amount of parallelism of each kernel would be far too small for any modern GPU. I expect this solution to be slower than a naive CPU implementation.

First things first, one need to find an efficient algorithm. The proposed solution runs in `O(n m²)` where `n` is the number of row and `m` the number of columns. That being said, the solution should be fast (ie. close to `O(n m)`) if most values are non-zero which is not the case in the example.

A more efficient solution is to first iterate over the `B` matrix and find the location of all the non-zero items so to put it in an array `L`. Then you can iterate over `A`, track the non-zero values and search for the closest index of `L` matching to the location of the current item in `A`. If the number of items in `L` is big for the target row (eg. >50), you can use a binary search so to find the location faster (since items of `L` are sorted). This solution runs in `O(n m log m)` time.

An even better solution is to iterate simultaneously over `A` and `L` like a [merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm). Indeed, the indices of `A` and the items of `B` are both sorted so the binary search is not even needed. When the index of the current non-zero item of `A` is bigger than the current item of `L` you can iterate to the next value of `L` (and memorize the last value of `L` discarded needed to compute the closest value). This algorithm runs in `O(n m)` (optimal). An efficient CPU implementation consists in computing chunks of raw in each many threads.

On a GPU, things are more complex since all the previously provided algorithm are not SIMD-friendly. Computing a row in an SIMD-friendly way turns out to be complex and generally inefficient (the overhead can be higher than the serial algorithm on a CPU). One possible solution would be to compute rows in parallel (1 thread per row) and transpose the matrix block per block in shared-memory so to perform SIMD-friendly memory accesses after that (assuming there is enough space). The non-zero values of A and B certainly needs to be extracted first so to avoid thread divergence as much as possible. This solution works only if the number of non-zero is relatively uniform between the lines (otherwise I doubt a GPU can actually be helpful). Note the overhead of the transposition can be significant compared to the computation. Thus, I am not sure it will be faster than a CPU based solution. In fact, if data lies on the CPU memory, then just transferring data to the GPU will certainly be more expensive than computing the result on a CPU in parallel.